# How to convert a String[] to an IDictionary<String, String>?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-objects

How to convert a `String[]` to an `IDictionary<String, String>`?

The values at the indices 0,2,4,... shall be keys, and consequently values at the indices 1,3,5,... shall be values.

Example:

```
new[] { "^BI", "connectORCL", "^CR", "connectCR" }
```

=>

```
new Dictionary<String, String> {{"^BI", "connectORCL"}, {"^CR", "connectCR"}};
```

Comment: This is similar to but not a copy of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624341/getting-pair-set-using-linq

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461367/linq-to-objects-return-pairs-of-numbers-from-list-of-numbers

Comment: If you need to this many times, I suggest you'll extract your favorite answer to an extension method `IDictionary<String, String> ToDictionary(this string[] arr)`

Comment: @HuBeZa: done before I saw your comment ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string,string> ArrayToDict(string[] arr)
{
    if(arr.Length%2!=0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Array doesn't contain an even number of entries");
    Dictionary<string,string> dict=new Dictionary<string,string>();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.Length/2;i++)
    {
      string key=arr[2*i];
      string value=arr[2*i+1];
      dict.Add(key,value);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

I'd recommend a good old for loop for clarity. But if you insist on a LINQ query, this should work:

```
var dictionary = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length/2)
                           .ToDictionary(i => array[2*i], i => array[2*i+1])
```

Comment: The only downside here is that you are forcing the creation of another collection (via Enumerable.Range).

Comment: Well, I would say that the other downside here is that this is godawful ugly and hard to read, as he suggests.

Comment: @Justin: The overhead should be minimal because Enumerable.Range is lazily evaluated. A couple of objects (enumerable + enumerator) and some integers (base, count, and maximum).

Comment: +1 for showing the linq way (and saying that readability suffers)

Answer (score 6):

There's really no easy way to do this in LINQ (And even if there were, it's certainly not going to be clear as to the intent). It's easily accomplished by a simple loop though:

```
// This code assumes you can guarantee your array to always have an even number
// of elements.

var array = new[] { "^BI", "connectORCL", "^CR", "connectCR" };
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for(int i=0; i < array.Length; i+=2)
{
    dict.Add(array[i], array[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: This. You can do it with LINQ, but I find a simple `for` loop to be much more readable (and obvious) in this situation.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram - You're right. By creating another collection with Enumerable.Range() it is possible to use LINQ. I upvoted your answer and agree that a for loop is still much more clear.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this maybe:

```
        string[] keyValues = new string[20];
        Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < keyValues.Length; i+=2)
        {
            dict.Add(keyValues[i], keyValues[i + 1]);
        }
```

Edit: People in the C# tag are damn fast...

Comment: The C# tag is like the old west. Must be quick on the draw.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896) as a dependency you can do:

```
strings
    .BufferWithCount(2)
    .ToDictionary(
         buffer => buffer.First(), // key selector
         buffer => buffer.Last()); // value selector
```

`BufferWithCount(int count)` takes the first `count` values from the input sequence and yield them as a list, then it takes the next `count` values and so on. I.e. from your input sequence you will get the pairs as lists: `{"^BI", "connectORCL"}, {"^CR", "connectCR"}`, the `ToDictionary`  then takes the first list item as key and the last ( == second for lists of two items) as value.

However, if you don't use Rx, you can use this implementation of `BufferWithCount`:

```
static class EnumerableX
{
    public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> BufferWithCount<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
    {
        if (source == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        }

        if (count <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
        }

        var buffer = new List<T>();

        foreach (var t in source)
        {
            buffer.Add(t);

            if (buffer.Count == count)
            {
                yield return buffer;
                buffer = new List<T>();
            }
        }

        if (buffer.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return buffer;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 and thank you. I'm not referencing Rx at the moment, but will try to remember this one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like other people have already beaten me to it and/or have more efficient answers but I'm posting 2 ways:

A for loop might be the clearest way to accomplish in this case...

```
var words = new[] { "^BI", "connectORCL", "^CR", "connectCR" };

var final = words.Where((w, i) => i % 2 == 0)
                 .Select((w, i) => new[] { w, words[(i * 2) + 1] })
                 .ToDictionary(arr => arr[0], arr => arr[1])
                 ;

final.Dump();

//alternate way using zip

var As = words.Where((w, i) => i % 2 == 0);
var Bs = words.Where((w, i) => i % 2 == 1);

var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(As.Count());

var pairs = As.Zip(Bs, (first, second) => new[] {first, second})
                .ToDictionary(arr => arr[0], arr => arr[1])
                ;

pairs.Dump();
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this is what I ended up with using a loop and implementing it as an extension method:

```
internal static Boolean IsEven(this Int32 @this)
{
    return @this % 2 == 0;
}

internal static IDictionary<String, String> ToDictionary(this String[] @this)
{
    if (!@this.Length.IsEven())
        throw new ArgumentException( "Array doesn't contain an even number of entries" );

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<String, String>();

    for (var i = 0; i < @this.Length; i += 2)
    {
        var key = @this[i];
        var value = @this[i + 1];

        dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    return dictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Linq

1. Select : Project original string value and its index.
2. GroupBy : Group adjacent pairs.
3. Convert each group into dictionary entry.

`string[] arr = new string[] { "^BI", "connectORCL", "^CR", "connectCR" };`

```
var dictionary = arr.Select((value,i) => new {Value = value,Index = i})
                .GroupBy(value => value.Index / 2)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.FirstOrDefault().Value, 
                                   g => g.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Value);
```