# how to convert string to Idictionary

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

```
 string putContactRequestBody = string.Format("<Contacts><Contact><Name>{0}</Name></Contact></Contacts>", contactName);
```

I want to convert putContactRequestBody to Idictionary

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670279/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-idictionarystring-string?rq=1

Comment: What do you mean by converting a string to a dictionary? Do you want to create a dictionary from the contents of the string, or to add the string to a dictionary?

Comment: Hello Actuallly I want to convert string to idictionary..Now I am able to do this .thanks for asking  Dictionary<string, string> obj = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            obj.Add("xml", PutItemResponse);