# How can I find the size of the largest subset where their maximum difference is 5?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, subset, counting

I have an array of numbers, and I am trying to find the size of the largest subset, such that all numbers in the subset are less than 5 apart.  They can assume to be sorted, if necessary.

For example:

```
[1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15]
```

4 is the largest subset. (5, 6, 8, 9)

I expect that there is a simple LINQ answer, but I am not thinking of it.  I could sort it and then iterate through it with each starting number, keeping track of the most from that number, but that seems very ugly and inefficient.  Any ideas?

---

Clarification on what I want to avoid:

```
(1,2,5) - 3
(2,5,6) - 3
(5,6,8,9) - 4
(6,8,9) - 3
(8,9) - 2
(9) - 1
(15) - 1
```

Comment: How did you downvote so fast??? I literally posted this question less than 10 seconds ago.  I guess you want to see sample code for what I am avoiding?

Comment: I'll work on it later this week (and Jewish year). 

Meanwhile take a look at:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624341/getting-pair-set-using-linq
in conjunction with the ConvertAll or Select function.  It's gonna be ugly...

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved by maintaining two pointers `left` and `right`.

Suppose you have a sorted array `array`of `n` numbers.

```
left = 0
right = 0
ans = INT_MIN
while right == n :
    if array[right] - array[left] < 5:
        right++
    else:
        left++
    ans = max(right - left + 1, ans)
```

Comment: This is answer for finding consecutive sequence, not a subset. And it is not even C#.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek As stated in my question, it can assume to be sorted.  And no its not C#, but it is still a helpful answer.

Comment: This greedy strategy will work. One can prove that the longest contiguous sequence of the sorted array will be the required subset.

Comment: From "I could sort it ... but that seems very ugly and inefficient." I expected it is not sorted, but ok, if it is sorted it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Start by making the biggest possible set at the beginning of the sorted list. Then keep removing values from the front until the next one fits, and add as many as possible after the next one too. This makes a new set. Keep track of the largest at any given moment.

Something like this in C#:

```
static IEnumerable<T[]> CloseSublists<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values, Func<T, T, bool> isClose) where T : IComparable<T> {
    var window = new Queue<T>();
    var enumerator = values.GetEnumerator();

    if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        return;
    }

    bool more;

    do {
        window.Enqueue(enumerator.Current);
    } while ((more = enumerator.MoveNext()) && isClose(window.Peek(), enumerator.Current));

    yield return window.ToArray();

    while (more) {
        do {
            window.Dequeue();
        } while (window.Count != 0 && !isClose(window.Peek(), enumerator.Current));

        do {
            window.Enqueue(enumerator.Current);
        } while ((more = enumerator.MoveNext()) && isClose(window.Peek(), enumerator.Current));

        yield return window.ToArray();
    }
}
```

and

```
public static T MaxBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> key) where TKey : IComparable<TKey> {
    var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
    enumerator.MoveNext();

    var max = enumerator.Current;
    TKey maxKey = key(max);

    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
        T current = enumerator.Current;
        TKey currentKey = key(current);
        int relation = currentKey.CompareTo(maxKey);

        if (relation > 0) {
            max = current;
            maxKey = currentKey;
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

used as:

```
int[] x = {1, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 15};
x.CloseSublists((a, b) => b < a + 5).MaxBy(l => l.Length)
```

Comment: This has some unnecessary copying with `window.ToArray()`; you can avoid it by combining `MaxBy` with `CloseSublists`. It kind of makes sense to do that, too; I originally thought something like `MaxBy` was built into .NET.

Answer (score 1):

Based on answer of Prince, I rewrote it to C# and improved a bit:

```
protected int MaxSubLen(int[] arr, int diffLessThan)
{
    int l = 0, r = 0;
    while (r < arr.Length)
    {
        if (arr[r] - arr[l] >= diffLessThan)
        {
            ++l;
        }
        ++r;
    }
    return r - l;
}
```

and, just for fun, the sequence returning generic version:

```
protected IEnumerable<T> MaxSubarray<T>(IList<T> arr, Func<T, T, bool> isClose_L_R)
{
    int l = 0, r = 0, start = 0;
    while (r < arr.Count)
    {
        if (isClose_L_R(arr[l], arr[r]))
        {
            start = l;
        }
        else
        {
            ++l;
        }
        ++r;
    }
    for (int i = start; i < start + r - l; ++i)
    {
        yield return arr[i];
    };
}
```

Comment: This looks like it gets the last subarray, not the largest one?

Comment: In some way both. It returns the last subarray it finds, but when it finds for example subarray of length 3, it never looks for subarrays shorter than 4. So the last it finds is the longest available.

Comment: Oh, `r` is just standing in as a short `arr.Count` in that last bit, then. Nice.